# "Log full requests/responses data" in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

The AWS [AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment StageDescription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-deployment-stagedescription.html) docs don't seem to reference the option "Log full requests/responses data" in the API gateway stage settings. I want to ensure it is turned off in cloudformation, how can I do this?

This shows the option I am refering to:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MethodSetting` are not property of `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`. Instead, they are property of `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` - [MethodSetting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html):

> The MethodSetting property type configures settings for all methods in a stage.

The [DataTraceEnabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-datatraceenabled) is the setting on the screenshot. Thus if you don't want it, set it to `false`:

> Indicates whether data trace logging is enabled for methods in the stage. API Gateway pushes these logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment has a "StageDescription" property. And StageDescription itself has the "MethodSettings" property.

Comment: do you need to redeploy the stage for it to take affect?